# Redux pushing to a nested array without mutating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a state object that looks like this:

```
PlaylistDictionary: {
  someId: {
    pages: []  // trying to push something to this array here
  },
  someId2: {
    pages: []  // trying to push something to this array here
  }, etc
}
```

I'm trying to update the "pages" array but I keep getting an error saying I'm mutating the state.. which I don't understand because if I'm making a copy of the state object with Object.assign... how am i mutating the state?  thank you for any help

```
case types.ADD_PAGE_TO_PLAYLIST: {
  let playlistDictCopy = Object.assign({}, state.playlistDict );

  if ( !playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].hasOwnProperty('pages') ) {
    playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages = [];
  }

  playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages.push( action.pageId );

  return Object.assign( {}, state, { playlistDict: playlistDictCopy } );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a shallow copy of the state object, you are not copying any of the property values at all, including the array itself, so you are mutating the array.

Your `.push` call changes the array, and since you haven't created a new array, that will affect all previously stored state objects as well.

You can do

```
playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages = playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages.concat([action.pageId]);
```

or

```
playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages = [ ...playlistDictCopy[ action.playlistId ].pages, action.pageId]);
```

to create a new array instead.