# Changing a property of all the objects in dictionary full of objects without mutating the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

To be short.. I'm trying to edit a property (selected) in all the objects of a dictionary.. but no matter what I do i'm mutating the state.  Can someone explain to me how to do it and why mine does not work?

I have this state:

```
{
  pageDict = {
    someId1: { prop1: prop1value, prop2: prop2value}, etc
    someId2: { prop1: prop1value, prop2: prop2value}, etc
  },
  playlistIndex: 0,
  playlists: [ somePlaylistId1, somePlaylistId2, etc ],
  playlistDict: {
    somePlaylistId1: { prop1: prop1Value, pages: [ someId1, someId2 ], etc }
    somePlaylistId2: { prop1: prop1Value, pages: [ someId1, someId2 ], etc }
  }

}
```

I have this reducer function:

```
case types.SET_SINGLE_PAGE_SELECT: {
  let pageDictCopy = Object.assign( {}, state.pageDict );
  let activePlaylistId = state.playlists[ state.playlistIndex];
  let activePlaylist = state.playlistDict[ activePlaylistId ];

  for ( let pageId of activePlaylist.pages ) {
    let page = pageDictCopy[ pageId ];
    page.selected = ( pageId == action.pageId );
  }

  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    pageDict: pageDictCopy
  });
}
```

EDIT: I have immutability-helper as well

Comment: This isn't immediately clear to me; it sounds like you're asking "how can I modify the state without modifying the state?".

Comment: im trying to modify the dictionary (pageDict) in my state without mutating it

Comment: Oh I see - this sounds very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655542/redux-pushing-to-a-nested-array-without-mutating-the-state).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i can do it if it's just one property.. but i dont know how to do it for multiple objects and a specific property.  why would i ask a question that got answered already.  I'm trying to learn Redux and am having troubles with it

Comment: `Object.assign( {}, state.pageDict )` will not do a deep copy, instead only the first level is cloned actually by value, but if those values are nested objects, they are not cloned, only the references are copied..

Comment: @webdeb okay gotcha so i gotta figure out how to deep copy then

Comment: @user1189352 google for `deep-clone` there are libs which are doing it properly, on the other hand it maybe simpler to refactor your reducer in a couple smaller one.. maybe..

Comment: @webdeb okay thank you for leading me in a direction, was feeling quite lost.  ty

Comment: @webdeb i solved this by refactoring my reducer as you suggested.  I decided to just use a reducer that changes just one object property (since i know how to do that) and just looped through it instead of trying to do the whole thing in one reducer.  ty again